# extract short url from Cutt.ly api code using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written some of the code for shortening urls using cutt.ly api in javascript .

I can see that urls are shortend but I am not able to extract shortened link from the response.
Please help

cuttly api info page link: https://cutt.ly/api-documentation/cuttly-links-api

> My code =====

```
let res = await fetch("https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=[keyHere]&short=https://www.google.com", {
      method: 'POST',
  });
  let shorturl = [];
  shorturl = res.json();
```

Comment: Also the http method is GET not POST.

Answer (score 0):

*res.json* returns a promise. You need to use *await*